Getting error while building apk using fvm
I am trying to build apk using following cmd fvm flutter build apk I am getting below mentioned error please suggest a solution.
Error:
PS C:\Users\ARcaN\Desktop\otrack_flutter_app> fvm flutter build apk

 Building with sound null safety 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDevRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile".

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 11s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          255.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Signing Configs
signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }


Your error  SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile" clearly says that you are missing signing details.
You need to add signing details like keyAlias, keyPassword ... under your android/app/build.gradle file
In short you need to let Android know about your signing details so that they can sign your app and provide you a release. you can create your debug build with signing detail
here are the sample format
signingConfigs {

    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

follow this article to know more about it
https://blog.codemagic.io/the-simple-guide-to-android-code-signing/

Signing config are already in the build.gradle, check editted code in question

can you add entire android/app/build.gradle file ? also i'm assuming you have keystore file and signing jks file
